# How to fix JSON parse error in Vuex with localStorage

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component, local-storage, vuex

I have setup Vuex in Vue.js and using it to update the state. After building login functionality on it I am trying to store the token in `localstorage` but when I add `localstorage` to state it is throwing an error.

my current code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { getAPI } from '@/axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    accessToken: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) || null,
    APIData: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    updateStorage(state, { access_token }) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
      state.accessToken = access_token;
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', JSON.stringify(access_token));
      // axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token.access_token}`;
      // sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', access_token);
    },
    destroyToken(state) {
      state.accessToken = null;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    loggedIn(state) {
      return state.accessToken != null;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    userLogin(context, usercredentials) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAPI.post('/login', {
          email: usercredentials.email,
          password: usercredentials.password,
        })
          .then((response) => {
            context.commit('updateStorage', { access_token: response.data.access_token });
            resolve();
            console.log(response.data.access_token);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    },
    userLogout(context) {
      if (context.getters.loggedIn) {
        context.commit('destroyToken');
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: what error is it throwing

Comment: @depperm Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: The value isn't valid JSON.  What's the value?  `console.log(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'))`?

Comment: @shob i get token value when from it.

Comment: That token value apparently isn't JSON...

Comment: Not sure why you have to involve localStorage.  Any way you could just store it directly in Vuex?

Comment: @shob I am sending json token from my backend. I can validate that.

Comment: It's clearly invalid JSON.  That's what the error means

Comment: @shob 

{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTQ4MTQzMTIsIm5iZiI6MTYxNDgxNDMxMiwianRpIjoiMjY4NDJlMDgtODVmYi00YTA5LTg4NDgtNjdmNmEzNmVkMDY4IiwiZXhwIjoxNjE0ODE1MjEyLCJpZGVudGl0eSI6eyJlbWFpbCI6InZlbjMzQGVtYWlsLmNvbSJ9LCJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.6Eq2pavUqOgxGXn6NmqpBa7TIxURq50tBH3uZ6pDOtk"
} 

this my token from api

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/soutqr1w/

Comment: What's the value of `console.log(response.data.access_token)`?

Comment: @shob i get straight token without any format.
current token i received:

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTQ4MTgzNDUsIm5iZiI6MTYxNDgxODM0NSwianRpIjoiMDI2YzU5YTQtMWZjYi00YmYzLTkwOWMtMjczYzIxNTk2OGRjIiwiZXhwIjoxNjE0ODE5MjQ1LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6eyJlbWFpbCI6InZlbjMzQGVtYWlsLmNvbSJ9LCJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.j9dqaBtIunlZv3dlggYorbuSmv6pceNfl9LQfcO7oag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're receiving raw encoding and creating an object wrapper for it in this format:

```js
{ access_token: 'eyJ0eX...' }
```

You shouldn't destructure it in the mutation payload.  Pass the whole object to `localStorage` if you're going to use `JSON.parse`:

```js
updateStorage(state, access_token) {
  state.accessToken = access_token;
  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', JSON.stringify(access_token));
},
```

Comment: so this how it should be ?
```state: {
    accessToken: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) || null,
    APIData: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    updateStorage(state, { access_token }) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
      state.accessToken = access_token;
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access_token);
    },
```

Comment: Look closely at my answer, I didn't do this:  `updateStorage(state, { access_token })`.  And you removed `JSON.stringify`?  I don't understand, you did something completely different than what I suggested....